# Как спарсить завершённые объявления на youl'e, не используя Selenium?

Tags: python, парсер

Мне нужно получить число завершенных объявлений у продавца с юлы [вот с этой странице](https://youla.ru/user/58ed89642c593e0907346c84/sold), но страница, как я понял подгружается при помощи *js* и из-за этого не удается получить весь *html* код.
Можно ли это как-то реализовать, не используя *Selenium*?
ps Использую Python 3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно эмулировать работу браузера, то есть посылать запросы на сервер так же, как это делает страница.

Скорее всего, там используется REST - архитектура, и скрипт начинает посылать запросы серверу ппосле того как страница загружена.

Можно перехватить эти запросы, посмотреть, как устроен протокол - наверняка, это не рокет сайенс - и сделать то же самое, но уже из своей программы.

Инструментов, котрые позволяют это сделать, довольно много, начать можно с Fiddler - он, конечно, мощный как танк (и иногад так же плохо заводится), но если его удалось запустить - то он своё дело сделает!

А еще можно сделать ппоиск по "rest youla" и попасть на [вот такой сайт](https://rest-app.net/api-youla) с документацией:
https://rest-app.net/api-youla

Дополнение. вчитался, и понял, что rest там очень даже не бесплатный. Возможно, способ самостотельно исследовать протокол всё же лучше. Но, также, возможно, что кто то это уже делал. Сходу удалось найти проект https://github.com/jesushatesu/parseYoula, и код там - довольно понятный и с комментариями. Надеюсь, поможет!